# Bottom 60 or so pixels are cut off, incorrect css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the following code but for some reason, I have an issue with part of the page being cut off which means pause/play/mute and fulls screen don't work on my flash object.

What am I doing wrong with the CSS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>2014-05-02_0203.swf</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <style>
            #header_container {
                background: url(../swf/table-images/gradhead.png) repeat-x #000;
                border: 0 solid #666;
                height: 80px;
                left: 0;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #header {
                color: #ECECEC;
                height: 80px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #container {
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 80px 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var width = window.innerWidth ||
                document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
                document.body.clientWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight ||
                document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
                document.body.clientHeight;
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {allowfullscreen: "true", menu: "false"};
            var attributes = {};
            swfobject.embedSWF("2014-05-02_0203.swf", "myContent", width, height-90, "9.0.0", "2014-05-02_0203.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFF">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header_container">
                <div id="header"><div class="headimage">
                    <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">
                    <img alt="" class="headimager" src="http://placehold.it/350x95"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="myContent">
                <h1>Alternative content</h1>
                <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### New CSS for ralph.m to see:

```
<style>
    #header_container {
        background: url(..//table-images/gradhead.png) repeat-x #0E4216;
        height: 80px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    #header {
        height: 80px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: do you have same probleme if you reduce width of your browser ? it might have to do with the ration of your flash. try not reset the width, leave to aut and see what happens

Comment: @GCyrillus ahh yeah, it's aspect ratio. I don't know how to solve that though and the javascript is actually not working correctly, it works on my screen of 1680x1050 but on my 1920x1080 if the window it always thinks the window is maximised even tho I have it as a small box...

Comment: `position: fixed` has its dangers. I'd try removing that to see what happens, as it causes the code you posted to be cut off at the bottom.

Comment: @ralph.m still doesn't fix it, I replaced the style sheet with the css in my last edit.

Comment: OK, it's probably necessary for us to see a link or a demo (jsfiddle or codepen etc.) to be able to see what's going on.

Comment: @ralph.m On testing on jsfiddle it shows correct, I uploaded the flash file to swfcabin.com, how would that fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Your content by itself does not expand the body (maybe because the flash-player uses some special quirky css) so, you can change that manually:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

So, I don't know exactly what you did wrong, but maybe this will help you.
(I had the same problem once, never got it why...)